# How do you make a proper HTTP POST request to an API via PHP code? I'm doing something wrong

Tags: php, apache, api, cakephp

So I am trying to authenticate with a url (in a companies API) and send some information in to be checked. If the info is good, it sends me back what I need (string). If not, it sends back a string: "0". If there is an error, it sends back a string complaining the error. However, using this method from the CakePHP documentation of HttpSocket, I am being returned an HttpResponse object that is seemingly empty. It has no body, no status code, etc. What am I doing wrong? I am going to change the values because they are private for work.

```
App::uses('HttpSocket', 'Network/Http');
    $user = 'username';
    $pass = 'password';
    $token = $this::_getToken($user, $pass);
    $hash = $this::_getChallengeSalt($token);

    $item = $this->Item->findById($id);
    $url3 = 'example.url.com/api/path/to/code';
    $http = new HttpSocket();
    $http->configAuth('Basic', $user, $pass);
    $data = array('id' => '1234', 'itemName' => $item['Item']['id'], 'hash' => $hash);
    $results = $http->post($url3, $data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have seen your code but could not fine any mistake

but here i can suggest you to if I think you cannot talk directly HTTPS, as it is HTTP encrypted with the public certificate of the server you are connecting to. Maybe you can use some of the ssl functions in php. But, this will take you some time and frankly, there are easier things.

Just take a look at [cURL](http://php.net/curl) (client URL), that has support for GET and POST requests, and also connecting to https servers.

let me know i can help you more.